# PHP Select from Mysql into onclick and echo an array

Tags: php

I'm trying to get my form to select its choices from a predefined mysql array (field_5806395ec1f8d)

Somehow I keep getting nasty `T_STRING` errors, but I can't figure out why.

(It's all wrapped in an `endcontent` variable btw)

```
<div class="xxx">
  <input type="text" id="select3" class="jsselect" placeholder="choose" value="'.$_POST[radio3].'">

  <div class="popup_select" id="select_div3"> $field = get_field_object("field_5806395ec1f8d");
    $i=2;
    foreach($field[choices] as $select){
    echo '
        <input id="select3_'.$i.'" onclick="radio(\''.$select.'\',3);this.form.submit();" name="radio3" value="'.$select.'" type="radio" '.($_POST[radio3] == $select ? "checked" : "").'>
        <label for="select3_'.$i.'">'.$select.'</label>
        <br>
    ';
    $i++;
    } 
  </div>

</div>
```

Any help will be gladly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You need PHP opening/closing tags...or if this is already in a PHP block `<div class="xxx">` is the first error. Add the error(s)..

Comment: See `<?php add code here ?>`

Answer (score 0):

A few mistooks in there and I'm not sure I've spotted them all but perhaps this might help? Field names in the POST array need to be quoted btw

```
echo '
<div class="xxx">
  <input type="text" id="select3" class="jsselect" placeholder="choose" value="'.$_POST["radio3"].'">

  <div class="popup_select" id="select_div3">';

    $field = get_field_object("field_5806395ec1f8d");
    $i=2;
    foreach($field["choices"] as $select){
    echo '
        <input id="select3_'.$i.'" onclick="radio(\''.$select.'\',3); this.form.submit();" name="radio3" value="'.$select.'" type="radio" '.($_POST["radio3"] == $select ? "checked" : "").' />
        <label for="select3_'.$i.'">'.$select.'</label>
        <br>';
    $i++;
    }
echo '
  </div>
</div>';
```

Comment: I would guess by the code there is no `<?php` before the HTML you put in an echo

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not directly no. It's wrapped into a function and in there into an variable

Comment: Ram, have another go

Comment: @RamRaider thank you but now I'm getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING) in config.php on line 75"

Comment: @LexLusa is line 75 part of the code you provided? You should identify the line (from the message I'd guess not). Also you should provide error messages when creating your question.

Comment: @chris85 Oh sry, yes it it it's the echo line in the foreach loop

Comment: Hey, I solved it just by wrapping my foreach into a function and echoing that function solved it. Thank you everyone